# Array member declaration and initialization

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to make `vertices` an array of `Vector`. But I don't know how to declare and initialize it. I tried this, but it complains:

```
class Mesh {
public:
    Vector  vertices[];
    int     verticesCount;
    Mesh();
    virtual ~Mesh();
};

Mesh::Mesh() {
    verticesCount = 4;

    vertices = new Vector[verticesCount]; // error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
    vertices[0] = new Vector(0, 0, 0);
    vertices[1] = new Vector(1, 0, 0);
    vertices[2] = new Vector(1, 1, 0);
    vertices[3] = new Vector(0, 1, 0);
}

Mesh::~Mesh() {
   delete vertices;
}
```

**Edit**

Trying to correct, applying your tips, I reach this:

```
Vector*     vertices;
//...
vertices = new Vector[verticesCount];
vertices[0] = Vector(0, 0, 0);
vertices[1] = Vector(1, 0, 0);
vertices[2] = Vector(1, 1, 0);
vertices[3] = Vector(0, 1, 0);
//...
delete[] vertices;
```

And it worked. But is it ok?

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: @Ankur - updated; in commment

Comment: If you're using C++, you should use `std::array` for arrays with sizes known at compile time, and `std::vector`for resizable arrays. Anyways, change your declaration of vertices to `Vector *vertices`

Comment: Time to read your C++ book again. This is not how to use arrays, and it is not how to use `new`. You won't be able to make `vertices` an array, but you can make it a dynamically allocated block (accessed through a `Vector* vertices`). But then... why not use an actual _vector_ for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `vertices` as an unspecified array of `Vector`, then you try to allocate memory for each entry in the array.

First C++ doesn't support empty arrays (if I remember correct), and the data type of the array is not pointers to `Vector` which means you can not use the `new` expressions.

If you want to use a dynamic array of vectors, please use `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<Vector> vertices;
```

And in the constructor:

```
vertices.push_back(Vector(0, 0, 0));
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Array members in C++ must have a compile-time fixed size.

If you want to specify the size of the array at runtime, you must either use a pointer, or preferably a `std::vector<Vector>`.

Comment: Not sure this is helpful - he's already using a pointer, and that's what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Corrections:

```
Vector*  vertices;
[..]
delete[] vertices;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring an array with an undefined size, compilers might also complain to this by issuing a *field has incomplete type* error.

Arrays are not pointers. Since an array is included in the memory footprint of the class the size must be known at compile time.

You can either:

- use a `std::array` if size is known a priori
- use a `std::vector` to have a variable sized array
- use a pointer `Vector *vertices` (or `Vector **vertices` since you are instantiating single vertices)